# How can tests fail in production?

Tags: apex, unit-test, failing-tests, production, winter14

This question is connected to my previous question here:
[User with read only profile updates records](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/21268/user-with-read-only-profile-updates-records)

We have a test case that started failing recently. It is also failing in production. As far as  I understand, winter release cannot be the reason, because SF team runs all tests of everyone , theey make sure that all tests pass before making a new release. So, how can tests fail in production ?

Comment: If your test case is using @SeeAllData=true or an older API version then there is always a possibility that is was dependant on production data that has now changed.

Comment: Another common reason for this is a validation rule that has been added in production that didn't exist when the test code was deployed.  The validation rule could now 'break' your test code in production.

Comment: Can you put out the error msg for the failure? Is it relating to your data not getting inserted or the assertions. Probably with this info we could narrow it down. I have had this issue many times due to the validation rule as @sfdc_ninja has already suggested

Comment: Your test could also be date dependent. I had some tests fail today (Nov 29th) because we were adding and subtracting months. This failing assert sums up what we were doing: `System.assertEquals(Date.today(), Date.today().addMonths(3).addMonths(-3));`. It failed with `Expected: 2013-11-29 00:00:00, Actual: 2013-11-28 00:00:00`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While Salesforce does run something called the hammer to ensure a release doesn't break functionalities, that doesn't guarantee that your test will never break in production.  This feature doesn't actually care whether the test failed or not, just that if it passed it doesn't fail after the new release (since lots of customers have failing tests in their org).

There are tons of reasons a test can fail in production, you'll need to review the specific test failures to find the cause. That being said, common ones are the addition of a new validation rule that a test method isn't complying with, or a test that references data in the production org that has been modified or deleted.